# Text to speech: Unable to switch to UK English

Tags: localization, text-to-speech

My phone (Fairphone) does not have the 'English (UK)' locale, only the US one. I recently discovered how to download custom voices for Google text-to-speech ('Install voice data' from settings) and have downloaded a UK English voice to replace the default American voice, which I find incredibly irritating (sorry, Americans!).
Unfortunately, even though I have downloaded the voice data, I still seem unable to switch to the new voice, as 'English (UK)' is still not an option when visiting TTS's 'Language' menu. Am I missing something here? How do I make my phone speak to me in my native language? (My Android version is 4.2.2)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked on my US-based xperia:

Settings > language & input > language (select English (UK))
Then back to language & input > text-to-speech output  > select google-text-to-speech engine then click on the settings icon next to it > language > english (UK)

Any luck? The key for me was to set the language first.

Comment: No, unfortunately the Fairphone only has one 'English' language option, and that's the US one. (No idea why, as a Dutch company, they made this decision, but that's a topic for another day!)

Comment: Are you using it in a specific situation? For example, Chrome has a language extension that might be a work around.  For navigation, Here has a very nice set that won't send you heading for the bolt hole.